# How to set/show icon using QStandardItemModel and QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a simple model that contain text and icon:

```
QStandardItemModel xmlModel;

QStandardItem * item1 = new QStandardItem( QIcon("qrc:/icons/resources/new.png"), "New" ) ;

QStandardItem * item2 = new QStandardItem( QIcon("qrc:/icons/resources/open.png"), "Open" ) ;

QStandardItem * item3 = new QStandardItem( QIcon("qrc:/icons/resources/save.png"), "Save" ) ;

xmlModel.appendRow( item1 );
xmlModel.appendRow( item2 );
xmlModel.appendRow( item3 );
```

I am using QML to show this model. Now I [know](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) I can use 'display' to show the text and 'decoration' to show the icon but the icon is not showing up.

My QML delegate code is the following:

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: parent.width
    height: 30

        Image {
            id: image

            source: decoration
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            height: parent.height
        }

        Text {
            anchors.left: image.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            //text: nameRole
            text: display
            //verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: image.verticalCenter
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {

                console.log("current index is " + index );

                root.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
                root.forceActiveFocus()
            }
        }
}
```

Am I not setting the `QIcon` correctly in the constructor?

Comment: I assume the issue is that `source` expects a path/an URL while the model returns a QIcon.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld right I can set other text roles and read it in qml but since this is `QIcon` is an issue. QML documentation does say its name is `docoration` in qml but how to really use it!

Comment: It appears that `decoration` can't be really used in QML after all (perhaps memory issues). I came around this by storing the image path in the model and than setting that to `image`element which worked good. If there was no other better answer, I will post my code as answer.